# Alimony in England

Tags: england-and-wales, court, alimony

My understanding is that alimony, in England, is decided by the courts. [This gov.uk page](https://www.gov.uk/money-property-when-relationship-ends/maintenance-payments), for instance, says:

> The court sometimes tells the person with the higher income to make regular maintenance payments to help with the other person’s living costs.

It's very vague, which I therefore interpret to mean "context is everything". However, are there any established rules of thumb that one can go by?

Examples:

- Say Spouse A has a higher income than Spouse B, but B's income is still a standard-deviation-or-two greater than the UK median salary?
- What if A has historically paid household bills out of B's expectation, even though B can afford it: Does that set a precedent against A, in the eyes of the court?
- What if B has plenty of savings -- from previous jobs, etc. -- but isn't necessarily drawing a salary at the time?

I assume the courts aren't going to be unreasonable, but -- to restate my question -- what circumstances and precedents are commonly factored into this decision?